# Doubling numbers in a loop giving unexpected results

Tags: c

Why is this happening? I imagined `8 *= 2` would be 16? I also tried `i += i` but got the same output.

As you can see from my code the aim is to get 2^1000.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 2;
    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < 1000; x++){
        i*=2;
        printf("%d\n", i);
        Sleep(200);
    }
    printf("%d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
4
8
10
20
40
80
100
200
400
800
1000
2000
4000
8000
10000
20000
40000
80000
100000
200000
400000
800000
1000000
2000000
4000000
8000000
10000000
20000000
40000000
80000000
0
```

Comment: "I'm sure there's more efficient ways of doing this " - Yes.  Since we deal with binary representation of numbers, simply shifting left will raise by a power of two.  BTW, read those as if they were base 16 and think about it.  Sure that's your actual code? Sure that's the actual format you're feeding to `printf`?

Comment: Overflow my friend. You cannot use an integer for that

Comment: Weird results, I tried on CodePad and it looks to be working as expected (http://codepad.org/y3hoZZQl)

Comment: @emecas: Doesn't explain the initial output, but yeah.

Comment: @nos: Probably.  What's your point?

Comment: @Emm, are you sure this is code that you're running into and the exact output?  I can't reproduce your problem, and it looks like a number of other people can't either.

Comment: @nos: Learning something is not redundant, regardless of what your compiler does for you.  Are you one of those that just disregards every optimization question asked here as "premature optimization herp derp"?

Comment: @Emm, are you printing in hexadecimal for some reason?

Comment: It took me a while to understand what your saying, that looks like a great way to do it. I'd still like to see why this isn't working though :/

Comment: Code has `printf("%d\n", i);`, output corresponds to `printf("%X\n", i);`

Comment: Hmm maybe it's my computer. I use a Compaq Evo

Comment: @Emm: No that would not be it

Comment: @Emm did you try using `%i` number format?

Comment: try copy and paste the **real** code, don't retype

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think this is the actual code you're running.  I think you've actually got:

```
printf("%x\n", i);
```

This would be an easy typo to make since you've also got a variable named `x` kicking around.

Alternatively, perhaps you somehow changed your integer print base.  The results *are* doubling, but you seem to printing them in hexadecimal.

```
0x004  =   4 decimal
0x008  =   8 decimal
0x010  =  16 decimal
0x020  =  32 decimal
0x040  =  64 decimal
0x080  = 128 decimal
0x100  = 512 decimal
```

Comment: Next, signed overflow is UB (well, signed integers can't technically overflow... but you know what I mean.)

Answer (score 1):

The sizeof(int) is most likely 32-bits on your system. Try using unsigned long instead of int. sizeof(long) should be 64-bits and by placing 'unsigned' in front will give you a wider range for positive numbers.

Also to printf() an unsigned long, use %lu

Comment: That's true the code won't solve the eventual problem, but it has nothing to do with the unexpected output where it looks like 8 x 2 = 10.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the numbers come out in hexadecimal. I have no idea why. Btw, you'll never reach 2^1000, because the highest number a 32 bit integer can store is 2^32 - 1.